# Mongoose - User Method not changing user

Tags: mongoose

Route

```
router.post('/users', (req, res, next) => {
  const user = new User()
  const { username, email, password } = req.body

  user.username = username
  user.email = email
  user.setPassword(password)

  user.save().then(() => res.status(200).send({ user })).catch(next)
})
```

Method

```
User.methods.setPassword = function(password, next) {
  bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then(function(hash) {
    this.password = hash
  }).catch(err => err)
}
```

The method was supposed to grab the password sent in the request body, hash it and set the in password field of the user instance. Even though the password is being hashed, it is not being set. I thought that it was because I was using arrow functions around this but it isn't the case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to call the next callback function after setting the hashed password i.e. after `this.password = hash` call `next()`

Comment: I checked if that was the problem and it isn't. With or without next(), it still does not work. Before that I was only using function(password) { } but I decided to see if that was the issue, unfortunately it was not.

Answer (score 0):

better way for hashing the pass is inside Model using this method

```
//hashing a password before saving it to the database
Model.pre('save', function (next) {
    let users = this;
    if(users.password) {
        bcrypt.hash(users.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            users.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    }
});
```

Then in controller

```
user.password = password
```

Comment: I usually do that way but I'd like to understand why it isn't doing the way that I'm doing - by using an instance method.